# Search for org-mode headings across all projects

Tags: org-mode

Is there a function to search for a heading in all org-mode files in all known Projectile projects?

I see that I can search for a string, but can I restrict it to an org-mode heading?;)

Comment: I don't know if `Projectile` provides a way to list all its projects, but Org mode certainly does not provide a way to list all Org mode files - AFAIK the only exception is the set of Org mode files that contribute to the agenda, which is stored in `org-agenda-files`. So you will probably have to collect the set of files in other ways. Once you have that set, you can loop over them and e.g. do `C-c / m ITEM={foo}` on each one: this command creates a sparse tree with the matching headlines unfolded. It's probably OK as an interactive method, but it might be awkward as a bulk method.

Comment: I guess there are various "obvious" approaches. But, I am wondering if you might mean 'across all project files'. Otherwise, it would be interesting to know how you search for a string across all of your projects, and it would be great if you could add that info to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve it is by taking inspiration from the `project-find-regexp` function. Instead of using files from the project, or from a directory, we give it all org files from all `projectile-known-projects`:

```lisp
(defun my-search-heading-across-projects ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((files (seq-filter (lambda (b) (string-match "org$" b))
                           (mapcan (lambda (root)
                                     (mapcar (lambda (f)
                                               (concat root f))
                                             (projectile-project-files root)))
                                   projectile-known-projects))))
    (xref-show-xrefs
     (apply-partially #'project--find-regexp-in-files "^\\*+" files)
     nil)))
```

This function will list all headings. You can then search for the heading using `isearch` (or narrow down if you use some completion framework like ivy/helm i.c.w. [helm-xref](https://melpa.org/#/helm-xref) / [ivy-xref](https://melpa.org/#/ivy-xref)), and subsequently jump to the 'selected' heading by pressing `RET`.

Comment: wow, now that's what I call finding things;). Superb. Thanks a bunch;)

Comment: This worked fine and I've been using it alot, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore;) It says: "(void-function xref-show-xrefs)". Not sure if I updated something.

Comment: Does it work after doing `(require 'xref)`?

Comment: Hmm, no, still the same

Comment: Ah, okay. It seems that the function is not available in the built-in xref.el for Emacs version < 29, so you should install xref from elpa to get the newer version (or update your Emacs to version >= 29).

Comment: ok, I'll do that, but it's so weird that it worked for two months;). Thanks. Also, while I got you on the line, is there anything like this, but for grepping?;) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75748/helm-projectile-grep-ag-in-all-known-projects

Comment: I guess you had xref installed from Elpa, possibly as a dependency. About the grepping question, I have posted a comment in the post under that link.