# Search in all Org mode headings within a folder

Tags: org-mode, search

Is there in Emacs such a function to search within all headings of all Org mode files within a folder or group of folders?

Comment: See the following similar question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74802/search-for-org-mode-headings-across-all-projects - as I said there, I don't know of a way to do a search across a set of Org mode files (unless they are part of your agenda files, or you create a temporary `org-agenda-files` list with just those files). I describe a method to search for headlines in a single file in there. If you combine those two ideas, you might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it searches and lists all headings. I want to be able to search for a specific heading, not list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from the answer given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74802/search-for-org-mode-headings-across-all-projects).
The following function will list all org mode headings in the directories passed to the function (more info in the docstring):

```lisp
(require 'xref)

(setq my-search-dirs '("~/.emacs.d" "dir-2"))

(defun my-search-heading-across-directories ()
  "Lists all org-mode headings in DIRECTORIES.
Takes any number of directories (separate by `SPC').

When called interactively then prompts for a directory after
which it lists all org mode headings in files of that directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((files (seq-filter (lambda (b) (string-match "org$" b))
                           (mapcan (lambda (d)
                                     (mapcar (lambda (f)
                                               (concat (file-name-as-directory d) f))
                                             (directory-files d)))
                                   my-search-dirs))))
    (xref--show-xrefs
     (apply-partially #'xref-matches-in-files "^*\+"
                      (mapcar #'expand-file-name files))
     nil)))
```

Functionality to subsequently easily search/narrow down over the headings is provided by packages like [helm-xref](https://melpa.org/#/helm-xref) and [ivy-xref](https://melpa.org/#/ivy-xref).

To search in multiple directories do

`M-:` `(my-search-heading-across-projects "~/dir-1" "dir-2")`

To call it with a list of folders, call it using `apply`.

There exists `xref-matches-in-directory` also, but it requires some 'trickery' to make it work with `xref--show-xrefs` while searching in multiple directories.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what it means to calling it using apply? I tried the above function (my-search-heading-across-projects). It prompted to select a folder. I did. Then I get: "helm-M-x-execute-command: Symbol’s function definition is void: xref-show-xrefs [2 times]"

Comment: Apparently, the function `xref-show-xrefs`, which calls `xref--show-xrefs` was only added in Emacs 29. In Emacs < 29 one should call `xref--show-xrefs` directly. I have updated the answer, where I have also fixed some other details. Please search the web for the meaning/usage of `apply` (and its difference from `funcall`) in elisp/Emacs.

Comment: Thanks, I however couldn't see what you changed in the answer. I copied again the code and got now the error: "helm-M-x-execute-command: Search failed with status 1: grep: repetition-operator operand invalid"

Comment: Can you try starting from `emacs -q`? (I've updated the code also with a 'require' now b.t.w.)

Comment: Thanks so much. I ran this last version from emacs -q, and got "user-error: Search failed with status 1: grep: repetition-operator operand invalid"

Comment: Too bad. Are you using GNU/linux? Or are you using some other system? Maybe you can try again while placing (one or) two backslashes before the plus sign in the regexp, so : `"^*+"` -> `"^*\\+"`

Comment: I'm on Mac Catalina, and just tried the last thing and same... :(. [edit:] Ok, now it worked after restarting. But it lists all headings! Would it be possible to SEARCH to find a heading, instead of listing all of them? :)

Comment: If you use some completion framework like vertico/ivy/helm, then you can further narrow down to some specific heading (as mentioned in the linked answer). If you are not using any of these, then you can use 'isearch' (`C-s`) to further search for some specific heading. Alternatively, you could modify the function and filter the results returned by `xref-matches-in-files` directly, but I would recommend you install one of the aforementioned completion frameworks (for simplicity I would recommend Ivy, which is what I use, but all of them are good).

Comment: Thanks. I could do that. The idea was to avoid this step, and retrieve only the headings that match the typing input as I have wrist pain. As I am no pprogrammer to do this on my own. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Well, you could also use the grep command directly. But then you would not miss the functionality to jump to the headline; I am not sure what is your goal. B.t.w., I just tested with vertico, but that does not work out of the box, so I would recommend Ivy or Helm, or use grep directly.

Comment: The purpose is to show a list of headings as I type from a selected set of predefined files or folders.

Comment: 'list headings as you type' sounds like you'd like to have some 'fuzzy finder' functionality. There are quite some packages providing such functionality (e.g. [affe](https://github.com/minad/affe), [ezf](https://github.com/mickeynp/ezf) and [fuzzy-finder](https://github.com/10sr/fuzzy-finder-el/tree/915a281fc8e50df84dcc205f9357e8314d60fa54)). However, the easiest would be to just install Ivy, and use the solution provided by this answer (it includes functionality to let you jump to the heading quickly also). Ivy is great for many reasons, you should really try it (incl. swiper, counsel).

Comment: I see from your newer questions that you are trying out helm now... so just use this solution with helm. Helm will automatically be used to present the results (list the headings), and you can use helm to further narrow down.

Comment: Yes, I use helm, but I have ivy installed too. I am confused as what the solution provided in this answer is :)) You mean, a two-step solution? 1) list the headings with the function above and then 2) use ivy or swiper or any occur function to find the specific heading?

Comment: No it will automatically list the results using Iyv or Helm... why don't you try it? (in your full installation, no need for 'emacs -q')

Comment: I don't know how :( I call `M'x my-search-heading-across-directories`, and then what?

Comment: If you call it with `M-x` then you can select the directory to list org headings from. You can also call it directly passing it directories you'd like to collect headings from using `(my-search-heading-across-projects "~/dir-1" "dir-2")` as mentioned already in the answer. Finally if you'd like to pass a list of directories then use `(apply #'my-search-heading-across-projects list-with-dirs)`. If it does not list headings, then maybe you have to add another backslash before the `+` in the regexp (I don't have MacOS here to find it out).

Comment: You mentioned in a previous comment that it already lists headings (with helm, if you got that installed), so then you can just type into helm to (fuzzy) filter out the heading you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks. But still (and sorry for the long thread), it will list all the headings in those directories. Then I have to take the extra step to find the heading with ivy or helm or swiper. My aim was to directly (with eg., (my-search-heading-across-projects "~/dir-1" "dir-2"), be prompted to type the words to match the heading (and not list all headings). Hope this time was clear!

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there less typing in my suggestion? Basically, if when you call the function it directly prompts you to type the string you want to find in the headings, you are skipping listing the headings first (by calling the function) and then typing C-o or any keybinding to search within the list. At least that is how I understand it! ;)

Comment: I've updated the answer, please try again to see what I mean, there is no extra typing compared to the other answer (when called via `M-x`, i.e. it prompts directly to find the heading). Before the update, there was the extra step of selecting directories, but I mentioned the option of using apply to pass the directories as a list. Anyway, now you can just configure the list like in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't prompt to find the heading.  I am getting `helm-M-x-execute-command: Search failed with status 1: grep: repetition-operator operand invalid`. I changed "^*\+" to "^\\\*+" (two backslashes) and it didn't spit any errors but it does the same as before: it lists the heading and I am not prompted for anything. I have to then type M-x helm-occurr or swiper to find the heading...

Comment: Ah okay... so it is not automatically listing it in Helm? Sorry then. I am just using vanilla Spacemacs, but probably Spacemacs has added some functionality to list this with Helm then...

Comment: Okay, I have found that it requires the package [helm-xref](https://melpa.org/#/helm-xref). I assumed this was simply configured by helm. I will again update the answer. Sorry, for the misunderstanding, and thanks for keep trying/and the feedback. B.t.w. I do think that this answer, i.c.w. helm-xref, does provide the nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks to you in any case for the time! Just to be clear, answering to your previous message, it lists ALL the headings found in those folders in helm. But the function doesn't prompt me to search within the headings. That is the issue. I would have to additionally use a key-binding like M-x helm-occur to find the heading I want to.

Comment: Did you see my latest comment (and the updated answer)? Because it mentions, that this functionality requires the package `helm-xref` to be installed. Then, you can narrow down, with helm (as usual in helm).

Comment: Finally... it worked! Million thanks! I had only to install that package!

Answer (score 2):

There is. You can search with [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html). For example, `M-x rgrep * todo` should list your TODOs. There's also a `grep-find` command you try.

Personally, I like a combination of helm and ripgrep, so to search all headings in the current directory I use `M-x helm-do-grep-ag ^\*+ foobar`.