# helm-do-ag in specific buffers / files

Tags: helm-ag

Let's say I want to create a function to search for a string in a set of files (orgmode files). Which of the helm-ag functions should I use and how is the syntax to add the buffers I want to include in the search? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `helm-do-ag`, and provide a list of org files as target, e.g. as follows:

```lisp
(setq my-search-dirs '("~/.emacs.d" "dir-2"))

(defun my-helm-search-org-files ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-files (mapcan (lambda (d)
                             (directory-files d t "\\.org$"))
                           my-search-dirs)))
    (helm-do-ag nil org-files)))
```

The function searches through org files in all directories in the `my-search-dirs` variable as set/configured by the first (setq) expression above. If you'd like to also search through subdirectories then use `directory-files-recursively` instead of `directory-files` (see its docstring for its usage).

As mentioned already, you could also just call 'helm-do-ag' directory with a list of file as follows:

```lisp
(helm-do-ag nil list-of-files)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and worked for individual files ((helm-do-ag nil list-of-files). However, for the directory, it prompts me to select the dir even if it is set in the function.

Comment: Did you load the code and do `M-x` `my-helm-search-org-files`? Because then it should ask for a pattern, which is the pattern you'd like to search for. Helm will search already while you are typing some pattern. Of course, you should set/configure the right directories first (in the first line of the example code).

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something wrong. I tried again and it works. Then I added the flag --follow to the base command helm-ag and it tracked the symlinks. Thank you!

Comment: The answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74874/26163) should work similarly, but it is a general answer (not helm/ag specific), and by default it searches only for org headlines (as was the question). I would ask you to try it again (now that you got helm installed).