# helm-projectile-[grep,ag] in all known projects

Tags: projectile, helm-projectile

helm-projectile-[grep,ag] works great, but how can I grep all known projects?;)

Is there a function already for that?

Comment: Do you have one directory containing all your projects? You could use `helm-ag` or `helm-rg` (or whatever recursive grep tool you prefer) starting from that parent directory.

Comment: no, it must be on a projectile level;)

Comment: I am not using helm (nor projectile), but from the documentation here it seems that you can select multiple projects to search through (and I guess there exists some simple helm shortcut to select all projects).